# Can you discard inactive jobs in Firefly

Tags: firefly

When you deal during your action and you finish having more then 3 inactive jobs in your hand, can you choose 3 to keep from all of your jobs or no ?

Game rules are not clear about this and in something that looks like [unofficial game FAQ](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http://flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/FAQ/Firefly_FAQ_v2.pdf&ei=GDRBU7XnAsiBywPz2oLQBQ&usg=AFQjCNFl-ofnAx8Vc7kdUt6B0BX-SYcm8g&sig2=t8D9aOlyic2ziB5kuzV_-Q) it looks like you can do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can end up with more than inactive 3 jobs in your hand after dealing, but you must immediately discard back to down to a maximum of 3.

Basically when dealing you consider 3 cards (these cards are not counted as being in your hand yet while you are considering them). You then select a maximum of 2 of these cards to keep depending on which ones you like (the selected cards, if any, are now placed in your hand). Then you must immediately discard back down to a maximum of 3 cards (so you would discard jobs you previously had that you didn't want to keep).

The FAQs hosted on flamesofwar.com are the official ones as they are linked to from [this official page](http://www.fireflythegame.com/howtoplay.aspx), although the version you linked to (v2) is outdated, [the most recent FAQ is v4.1](http://www.flamesofwar.com/Portals/0/all_images/GF9/Firefly/Rulebooks/FAQ/Firefly_FAQ_v4.1.pdf).